# How can I import an iTunes library from XML while preserving the "date added" field?

Tags: macos, itunes, mojave, filesystem

I have an `iTunes Music Library.xml` file and an `iTunes Media` directory. The "date added" fields in the XML file are correct. The "date created" file attributes are correct. However, when importing into iTunes, the "date added" field is set to today's date. I would really like to preserve this information.

I'm importing the library by deleting the contents of the `iTunes Library.itl` file. This causes iTunes to rebuild from the XML file. I'm using Mojave 10.14.6 and iTunes 12.9.5.

I think I heard some mention of `iTunes Library.itl` being a SQLite database. I haven't actually checked this. If that's the case then it might be possible for me to spend a few hours manually changing the fields of each individual song (or spend twice as long trying to automate the process!). If what I've suggested is possible I would be willing to do it (because I really want the information intact) but I'm hoping there's an easier way.

If the `iTunes Library.itl` is not a SQLite database then surely there must be a tool out there that I can use to modify it. Can AppleScript do it? Perhaps there's a tool that converts the XML file to an ITL file while preserving the date added field?